# jquery how to clear out modal input fields for reuse

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal form using jquery and twitter bootstraps. I have set up the modal so when the person cancels the form, / closes the modal i clear out the input fields. however if the person activates the modal again and enters values in to the fields, the dom still sees the field value as null.

here is my form html

```html
    <div class="modal fade in" id="forgotPassModal" data-b-view="ForgotPass" data-brite-cid="bview_1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" style="margin-top: -152.66666662693024px;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Security questions:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            Please answer the following security questions, click 'Submit', and you
            will receive an email containing instructions on how to change your password.
        </p>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset id="forgotPassForm">

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="span3" "label_4"="">What was the last name of your third grade teacher?</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-large" id="forgotPass_4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="span3" "label_165"="">What is your maternal grandmother's maiden name, please provide full name?</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-large" id="forgotPass_165">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary forgotPassSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my jquery

```js
for (var i = 0; i < $forgotPassQuest.questionId.length; i++){
        var questionId = $forgotPassQuest.questionId[i]['id'];
        $('#forgotPass_' + questionId).val(null);
    }
    
    $('#forgotPassModal').modal({show:true})
    $('.forgotPassSubmit').click(function() {
        var questAnswered = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < $forgotPassQuest.questionId.length; i++){
            var questionId = $forgotPassQuest.questionId[i]['id'];
            questionField = $('#forgotPass_' + questionId);
            questionFieldVal = questionField.val();
            if (questionFieldVal == '' || questionFieldVal == null){
                questAnswered = false;
            } else {}
        }
        if (questAnswered == true) {
            submitAnswers();
        } else {
            alert('please complete your security questions.');
        }
    })
    $('#forgotPassModal').on('hidden', function () {
        $('#forgotPassModal').remove();
    });
```

now the form is dynamic and can change from user to user. Any ideas on a way t clear the form out on cancel/close but still let the value be recognized when the user does change the value?

Answer (score 0):

By using "remove" `.remove()`, you are effectively dumping the entire DOM intro the trashcan which removes ALL event listeners.

Thus, you should only hide your modal OR clear the body using `$('.modal-body', '#forgotPassModal').empty();`.

Comment: Additionally I would suggest loading your modal-body each time with AJAX. Simply request the URL where the RAW HTML is located. :)

Comment: That's a terrible idea. The contract between calling code and ajax should be that contents are json, and should only be data attributes (userId, userName), not full-blown html. This way the ajax can be used elsewhere.

Comment: That's not true at all.  People regularly return HTML (and JavaScript) from AJAX calls.  If you look at the .ajax() method definition on the jquery website, you'll see that the dataType parameter can be xml, json, script or html.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: By using this Whole Body Gets Empty .. we cannot pass HTML Elements Every time .. Only Value Must be get Empty

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the `div` from `DOM` you can "reset" the values of the inputs.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dMbXV/

```
$('#forgotPassModal').on('hidden', function () {
    $('input').val('');
});
```

Comment: I tried the above code and setting the val to ''  and a no longer removing the content from the div. However when I reactivate the modal enter values in the field, and submit i see the values are '' versus the values I just typed in. do I need to do something on change?

Comment: Interesting. Is the hidden event of the modal performed before the form submits?

Comment: in the test case I was given yes. Use activates modal then cancels out. then activates the modal answers and submits. the dom is saying there are 4 inputs event though I only see two in the page visually and in the resulting code.

Comment: If the hidden is called before the form submit the inputs will be cleared out and be empty on post.

Comment: thats not what I am seeing if I put $('#forgotPassModal input') in the webkit dev tools I will get 4 inputs back. So i need a way to clear out the inputs from the dom but not affect the modal, I have tried .val('') , .val(null) , I have removed the but the dom keeps holding on to the old empty values. so when I I submit the form on the second round I still get 4 fields responding even through the form physically has 2.